# How to place hyperlink on bootstrap typeahead?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I need to place hyperlink on every typeahead auto suggest value like if we search "los-angeles" then my `losangele.html` open on "losangeles" selection. My typeahead code is following

```
// Multiple DataSet

        $('input.countries-cities').typeahead([
            {
                name: 'Canada',
                local: ["Toronto", "Montreal", "Calgary", "Ottawa", "Edmonton", "Peterborough"],
                header: '<h3>Canada</h3>'

            },
            {
                name: 'United States',
                local: ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Houston", "Philadelphia"],
                header: '<h3>United States</h3>'

            }

        ]);
```

and my html is this

```
<div style="float: left; width: 500px">
                <h4>Search Your Countries or City</h4>
                <input class="countries-cities typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Countries And Cities">
            </div>
```

Comment: by default hyperlink is placed , i think you have to modify the source to update the href value. can you provide a fiddle to play arround

Comment: You can view complete code at here
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=typeahead-with-local-dataset